# Angular: How to assign a List returned by Spring Model to Angular Object?

Tags: java, spring, angular, typescript, spring-mvc

I have a requirement where am setting up a `List` of objects as `model attribute` in `spring controller` and I need it to assign to an object in `angular .ts` file.

Here is what I need to do. My java object:

```
public class Lab {
   //some members of the class
}
```

This is how am adding it to `Model`:

```
public String getIndexPage(@RequestParam(value="val") List<Lab> labs, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("val", labs);
    return "index.html";
}
```

The corresponding object in `Angular` named inside `lab.ts`:

```
export class Lab {
// same variables as in java
}
```

And here is the `component.ts` file where I need to assign the `val` list:

```
export class VideoFormComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedValues: Lab[] = new Array(4);

  ngOnInit() {

     this.selectedVideos = "${model.val}"; //assignment statement
  }
```

But here is where am getting the error which says:

```
Type '"${model.val}"' is not assignable to type 'Lab[]'
```

What is the correct way to use that list inside the script file?

Answer (score 0):

`"${model.val}"` is just a string in Typescript.

If `model.val` is an array of objects that are shaped like `Lab[]`, you can do `this.selectedVideos = <Lab[]>model.val`.

If `model.val` is an array already typed as `Lab[]`, you can simply say `this.selectedVideos = model.val`

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I'm assuming you're using Angular HttpClient or websocket or something to first get the data from a server endpoint to the client.

Comment: Cannot find name 'model' is the error. Have already tried this.

Comment: Ok see my edit then, you can't just teleport data from Spring to Angular :)

Comment: You will need a REST api or similar on your server so you can actually get it to the client, for which refer to: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: You are confusing serverside and clientside rendering. Angular needs to get the data via a service from a rest-endpoint. The expressions ${...} will never be rendered as the template should be a static resource.

Comment: The reason I did it this was because the requirement was to send both the data as well as load the index.html page. Its like sharing the state of a web application with other user via a link. So first I create an API for that link which populates data and then tried to add it to attribute so that I could populate some field when the link is loaded or hit.

Answer (score -1):

How are you providing the `model` data to the angular component? If your data comes from a Http request you should create a service that makes the request and then call it from your component and set the result in the `selectedValues` variable. Or if you are providing the data as an input to the component you should use the @Input decorator. In either case the data is provided externaly to the component. For what I read, you are trying to use a `model` object that has a `val` attribute, but you are not providing it anywhere.

Comment: Thats what I want to know. How can I use `val` in the component. I do have a `get` service which is invoked first from a url, with the `requestparams` it fetches data from DB and creates a list. It then redirects to `index.html` and sets the list as model attribute.